# Issue when changing Joomla! 3.1 server

Tags: webserver, database, migration, joomla3

I am changing my Joomla server from last host to another (the domain changed to).

**First** I made a ZIP backup with all of my instalation files (even `.htaccess`/`php.ini`/etc...), I mean, ALL files from my old host.

**Second** I upload my zip file into my new server and unziped to public_html folder

**Lastly** I made a backup of my db from old domain & host and replace all db changes of my `configuration.php` (db name, user, password - the prefix of db remained the same).
So far so good.

My back-end works nicely, all function and stuff stills the same.
The problem is my front-end, doesn't show nothing looks like my last site at the old host.
I checked out my `.sql` file of my backup and I saw that it calls the root of my last server (gloper56). I already tried to change all calls from my last domain to the new one and if I do this it simply breaks my back-office.
This is the [old](http://www.gloper.org/highplay.pt) host, and this is the new host (just copy/paste this link, SE doesn't allow me to put IP as a link `http://188.93.229.100/~highplay/` (without right domain cause I need to fix this before change nameservers).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue simply using an Extension named [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/).
This is a free extension that gives all access to a clean backup Joomla! site (even domain migration and host migration). Just showing some love for this awesome extension. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with 404's which means that files/folders can't be found for example:

`High%20Play%20Institute%20-%20Multime%CC%81dia_ficheiros/modal.css`

This is returning a 404. You need to ensure that this folder exists on the new server, because at the moment it does not exist in the relative path. If the folder is there then ensure that the folder has correct read permissions as well as belonging to the right user group in order to view those folders/files.

Comment: I did not remember the way figuring errors in Firebug. So, this is a mess, for two reasons: `High Play Institute - Multimédia` is NOT my homepage, and when I check the template view in my back-end, it works very well. I do not have a folder named _ficheiros_, nor even some like `High%20Play%20Institute%20-%20Multime%CC%81dia`. Other issue is that all menu links is linking to my old domain, so I guess that this problem lies in sql (for example, sql is calling for my OLD home root). Am I right?

Comment: No, not necessary your template files may refer to the old domain.